# Writing to an Excel file from SQL Server Database

Tags: c#, sql-server, excel

Currently, I need to be able to retrieve values from an SQL Server DB, populate an Excel file according to a *certain template*, and then allow the user to download the file. I also need this this *certain template* to be customizable, in the sense that the user can add new fields, and remove fields.

I understand that there are a couple of approaches I can take: using **.xlt**, and using **C#** directly. With C#, the user will need to interact with a UI, which will then populate a ExcelTemplate table in the SQL Server. This ExcelTemplate table will then be used when the user wishes to download a new Excel file.

I know all this stuff may sound kinda abstract, so please do tell me if there are some places I need to elaborate/clarify. Thanks a bunch, man.

**EDIT:** Sorry, I kinda missed this part out, but I'd prefer to allow the user to customize these Excel templates via a Silverlight UI.

Comment: when you say templte you mean you create a specific structure for excel

Comment: Yup, kinda. I only need it in a certain format, however (e.g. fieldname - column name/formula - unit type).

Comment: can you create the format manually and then fill it up

Comment: Sorry, I hope this format writing thing can be done on Silverlight!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

at the end of the day I think I'm gonna spend some time building a customized dashboard. It won't be generic, but rather focused on the existing database.

I know this answer is kinda vague and all, but I'd like to say thanks for all the help :) it'd be great if there are dynamic solutions for this in the future! I think...

Answer (score 1):

1. You can create Data Sources in Excel and pull the data from MS SQL Server.
2. You can use MS Reporting Services which allow to get reports in MS Excel format.  In this case users can [use Report Builder to customize the reports](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd220460.aspx).

Comment: I took a look at the Report Builder; it looks pretty cool and stuff. But I'd like it if the same functionality could be provided on Silverlight!

Answer (score 1):

For pulling down data from SQL Server and dumping it into Excel, you can use [Officewriter](http://www.officewriter.com/officewriter-for-sql-server-reporting-services.aspx). It has Reporting Services integration and supports generating .xls and .xlsx documents. There's also a template component that basically does what you're trying to do. The templates are actually Excel documents, so the users can edit them directly in Excel. Not Silverlight, but not bad. You can try an [eval](http://www.officewriter.com/officewriter-free-evaluation-b.aspx) for free.

DISCLAIMER: I'm one of the engineers who built the latest version.